# Is my Math.SE question on numerical method error more relevant on SciComp?

Tags: discussion

Here is the question: [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2609970/kernel-based-differentiation).

If it's a better fit, I'll ask the Math.SE mods to migrate it.

I suppose this meta question could be about the more general case about posting here vs on Math.SE when the question is about the error analysis of a numerical method. How should I decide where to post when I have a question on this topic?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Numerical analysis questions, such as error analysis, are definitely on topic here.  I would say that there is a good number of people on this site with sufficient experience to answer up to standard graduate level numerical analysis questions.  Beyond that (e.g. at or near the cutting edge of research), it may be hard to find anyone on earth able to answer it, much less someone on this site.  Even though we certainly welcome such research-level math questions, I might recommend the math overflow site for this purpose.

Comment: Sounds good. What would be your call for the linked question?

Comment: @VF1: it is certainly worth a try here on scicomp.  It might help if you give a little more context to the numerical side of your question rather than just the purely analytical side.

Comment: Actually, even for research-level numerical analysis and (applied) optimization questions, I'd recommend this site over MathOverflow (exhibit A: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/na.numerical-analysis).